# rotate wide commutative diagram tikzcd

Tags: tikz-cd

I have a very large commutative diagram that is too big for the margins. I have shortened the names of the objects as much as possible. I have tried using the option [cramped] and setting the column sep to be smaller. It's just too big. Is there a way to rotate the entire diagram 90 degrees?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
 ObjectWithLongName \arrow[r]
 & ObjectWithLongName \arrow[r]
 & ObjectWithLongName \arrow[r]
 & ObjectWithLongName \\
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put the diagram in a `\rotatebox`.  Because the catcode of `&` will be fixed when passed as an argument, you have to use `ampersand replacement`.  Otherwise you will get uninformative errors like

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \pgf@matrix@last@nextcell@options
```

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\rotatebox{90}{%
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
 ObjectWithLongName \arrow[r]
 \& ObjectWithLongName \arrow[r]
 \& ObjectWithLongName \arrow[r]
 \& ObjectWithLongName \\
\end{tikzcd}
}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always change

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
 ObjectWithLongName \arrow[r]
 & ObjectWithLongName \arrow[r]
 & ObjectWithLongName \arrow[r]
 & ObjectWithLongName 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

which can't fit the page margin

[image]

to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
 ObjectWithLongName \arrow[d]\\
 ObjectWithLongName \arrow[d]\\
 ObjectWithLongName \arrow[d]\\
 ObjectWithLongName 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

The latter code above will produce

[image]